# how to taskkill an input output process

Tags: batch-file, taskkill

Quite new to batch script, please help me out.

```
set Pathname="C:\S3Sync" 
cd %Pathname% 
S3Sync.exe -
timeout /t 10 
taskkill /im S3Sync.exe
```

I want to run the following process and if it stops or goes into an infinite time period, kill the process after 10 seconds and also use try and catch to get the error. what are the possibilities of using such statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These commands may help you:  Put them after the `timeout` command

```
set err=%errorlevel%
tasklist |find /i "s3sync.exe" >nul && taskkill /f /im S3Sync.exe
```

If your task hangs then the errorlevel will not be set correctly, of course.

Comment: set Pathname="C:\S3Sync" 
cd %Pathname% 
S3Sync.exe -AWSAccessKeyId 4444 -AWSSecretAccessKey 444444 -SyncDirection upload -LocalFolderPath "C:\bingunzippedfolder" -BucketName garbage     set err=%errorlevel%    if err >nul tasklist |find /i "s3sync.exe" >nul && taskkill /f /im S3Sync.exe   , is this the way the script will check.